# how to get textbox value on grouped rows(jquery-datatables.net plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data table having data of 10 pages  with grouped rows(expand/collapse)(using datatables (v 1.10.5 & rowgrouping.js). everything is working fine . But by using this

```
var copy = $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).find('input[type="number"]').each(function(){  
    $(this).data('original',this.value);
});
```

I'm able to get values of all textboxes in OTable except grouped rows.
How to get textbox values which are on grouped rows(i.e., expand/collapse rows) also.

Comment: how does the generated html look like?

Comment: @Legends it's similar like(example source) : https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/collapsibleGroups.html . for every grouped row i have a textbox

Comment: what happens when u expand the grouped row, is the data already inside or is going to be downloaded yet?

Comment: expand & collpase is working fine . i just want values of textboxes on those grouped rows  when user enters text into it.

Comment: The query looks good (u filter them by attribute type value), can't say anything without the generated markup or setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Legends sorry i vl try that.but  the  only thing i changed  in rowgrouping plug-in is the grouped row colspan less than the total columns  . so grouped row will appear till before of last column .in last column i have textbox